# Is my recursion solution to this problems correct?

Tags: c, function, recursion

I need to solve this by recursion, here is what they ask to do:
Write a recursion function that takes a positive number and returning the sum(+,-) of its digits from right to left, like this way(for example): the number is 56894, the sum is 4-9+8-6+5=2.
Another example, the number is 7762348, the sum is 8-4+3-2+6-7+7=11.

Does my solution below is correct? I tried compiling it with a lot of numbers and it seems to be correct, but need to be sure.

Here is my recursive solution:

```
int func(int num){
  if(num/10 ==0) 
    return num;
  return (num%10) - func(num/10);
}
```

Comment: If it works on paper, works in code tests *including* corner/edge cases, and doesn't invoke undefined behavior, it's probably correct. Regardless, "working" code asking for reviews belongs on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), not here.

Comment: this is tagged [tail-recursion] - the code in question does *not* use a tail call

Comment: Code also works for `func(0)` so perhaps extend to "function that takes a _non-negative_ number".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution seems to be correct -- the problem asks you to do:

```
ABCD -> D - C + B - A
```

But your code does:

```
ABCD -> (D - (C - (B - A)))
```

Though it's not hard to show that:

```
(D - (C - (B - A))) == (D + -1 * (C + -1 * (B - A)) == D - C + B - A
```

Or some similar informal proof.  But is the code considered *correct* if it computes `num/10` twice instead of using a local variable to store the quotient:

```
int func(int number) {
    int quotient = number / 10;

    if (quotient == 0) {
           return number;
    }

    return number % 10 - func(quotient);
}
```

Alternatively, this seems like an opportunity to play with `div()` and `div_t`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>  // where div() and div_t are found

int func(int number) {
    div_t result = div(number, 10);

    if (result.quot == 0) {
        return number;
    }

    return result.rem - func(result.quot);
}
```

Possibly avoiding yet another division on each iteration.

Comment: I got yours, but when I compile my code it works fine.... so what would be the problem if it compile the same way? and the result are the same?

Comment: @sam0101, they both produce the same results.  The difference is the example I provided tries to do less work to achieve those results.  It's the next subtle step from getting it to work to trying to get it to work well.